# LARAVEL 5.3 template Blade não está atualizando a página

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, template, laravel-blade

Bom dia.

Sou iniciante no framework PHP Laravel e estou com a seguinte dificuldade:

Eu escrevo o meu html dentro do meu arquivo .blade.php e chamo ele em uma view na Route mas as informações que eu atualizei no código não estão aparecendo no navegador, a página fica estática sem atualizar as informações novas mesmo dando CTRL+F5, mas se eu tiro a extensão .blade.php e deixo só .php as informações aparecem. Li várias páginas na internet e várias deram a solução de setar a permissão 777 na pasta /storage dentro do meu servidor ubuntu que está rodando o apache2. Alguém encontrou esse erro recentemente e conseguiu dar uma solução para ele?

Obrigado.

Comment: Olá, teria como postar o seu código para analisarmos? Principalmente a parte em que faz a chamada da view e o nome exato do arquivo .blade.php

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow, sua pergunta não fornece muitos detalhes. Leia isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: você não precisa escrever `.blade.php` na URL, digite apenas o nome da rota que carrega a view.

Comment: Poste o seu código!

Comment: Você precisa nos dar mais detalhes, coloque uma parte do código que você acha que está o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa digitar `.php` ou `.blade.php` na URL para acessar uma pagina, utilize apenas o nome da rota que `retorna (return)` a `view`, por exemplo;

```
Route::get('home/paginax', function(){
    return view('minhaview'); // Este é o nome do arquivo
});
```

Dentro da sua pasta `resources/views` crie um arquivo com o mesmo nome que você usará para fazer o `return`.

`minhaview.blade.php`.

Para acessar a pagina apenas utilize a url como no exemplo abaixo;

`meudominio.dev/home/paginax`

Comment: Boa tarde Rafael! Eu não estou digitando a extensão para chamar a URL no navegador e também não estou digitando a extensão no return da minha Route. O problema é que se deixo a extensão .blade.php no arquivo mesmo, dentro do meu diretório resouces/views e chamo esse arquivo na minha Route, as atualizações que fiz no código não aparecem no navegador, se eu tiro a extensão .blade do arquivo e deixo só .php as informações aparecem.

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema! eu atualizava, removia coluna da table ou adicionava e nada acontecia! vou descrever como resolvi e você verifica se resolve para você, Sobe seu projeto para um repositório de código como o Assembla! nesse momento ele sobe apenas o seu projeto, bem limitado com um tamanho bem menor do que o que está no seu computador! efetua checkout dele e aplica o comando composer install no console em linha de comando! ele vai instalar as dependências e atualizar os arquivos necessários ! Mas faça Backup por segurança!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Tive o mesmo problema e sou novo com o framework. Consegui solucionar (não gostei da solução) renomeando a pasta que armazena as views. Obs: limpei os caches com o codigo `php artisan cache:clear` e não surtiu efeito. Tomara que tenham uma solução melhor do que trocar o nome da pasta.